# Запуск выполнения скрипта PySpark на кластере

Tags: apache-spark

При запуске скрипта **PySpark** в режиме кластера с помощью **Apache Zeppelin** выдается следующая ошибка:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.kafka.KafkaRDDPartition
```

Т.е. на нодах не находит класс.
Как его добавить, чтобы все ноды его подхватывали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запускать Spark Submit с опцией `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.0.2`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.